# Migrate Angular 1.2.16 to 1.6.9

Tags: angularjs

I know many of you are asking how to migrate from Angular 1 to Angular 5. Or from 2 to 5. But my question is a little different. I have my personal application written in Angular 1.2.16 and I would like to know:

```
1. Is it worth to migrate at all?
2. How complicated that will be?
```

I know there is a change log in Angular's gitlab which is good thing but it is huge in between two versions. Most of the changes are bugfixes. But is there a lot of incompatibilites between those two versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you cannot migrate directly from angularJS 1.2 to 1.6.9, it will be more difficult this way.

You have to make it step by step by looking to this migration guide:

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration

They exposed detailed way to do it from:

```
1- Migrating from 1.2 to 1.3
2- Migrating from 1.3 to 1.4
3- Migrating from 1.4 to 1.5

Last step:
4- Migrating from 1.5 to 1.6
```

So you can look at each step and see the changes that you can modify and test if it works as expected.

it can be more time consuming this way but the level of success can be more important.